# Bind an ICommand to a TabItem WPF (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, tabitem

I have a TabControl with a few TabItems. I want one of my TabItems to act as a button. When I click on the TabItem, I want it to execute a Command in my associated ViewModel. I have the following code in my View:

```
         <TabItem  Header="Manage Users" Visibility="{Binding IsAdmin, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=OpenLoginCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TabItem>
```

The OpenLoginCommand is an ICommand in the ViewModel. I have the interactivity namespace defined. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's your issue? If the command is not working, what's the Output window saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`

```
<TabItem  Header="Manage Users" Visibility="{Binding IsAdmin, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=OpenLoginCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Assign `EventTrigger` to `<TabItem.Header>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396518/binding-a-tabitem-in-wpf If you assign it to `<TabItem>` it will trigger when you click inside the tab content.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MouseDown` instead of `MouseLeftButtonDown` as referencing [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.aspx) the latter event doesn't exist on a `TabItem` control.

If your requirements insist on left-button only, then check the state of the mouse within the command.